# Microservice authentication - how to keep the token in the browser between subdomains

Tags: javascript, html, microservices

I consulted the entire web and found no solution. I am creating a microservice structure. There are several systems. There will be a single authentication location. After authenticated, the user will be directed to the microservice (which is another system).

The system is SPA and authentication will be performed with JWT. My question is how do I get the token on different domains. I thought of saving to localStorage, but it is stuck in the domain.

How can I save a token in the browser, change domain and retrieve that tokan?

Example of google that the user leaves gmail and enters the google drive sharing the access token.

Comment: I would do some research into how single sign on systems do it, because it's basically the same kind of deal. I suggest that a certificate system might be a better bet than JWT.

Answer (score 0):

A couple approaches I can think of:

- Cookies can be shared between top-level domains (`foo.example.com`, `bar.example.com` can use a `example.com` cookie)
- You can have a cooperating authentication service in a single domain that your user has authenticated with, and your microservice frontends communicate with it suitable CORS settings. (eg. `auth.example.com`, with to allow various `something.example.com` services to talk to it).